# Set the size of font text for weights and nodes labels in igraph package

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to draw a small graph increasing the size of its fonts. For example, the following code:

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","s"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("s", "s", "s", "a", "a", "f","f","a","e","a","d","d","b","e"),
                          to=c("a", "f", "e", "e", "f", "e","d","d","d","b","b","c","c","c"),
                      weight=c(3,5,10,6,6,5,5,8,3,11,2,6,3,13))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices=actors)


g %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "label", value = relations$weight) %>%
  plot(vertex.size=30,vertex.color="white", vertex.label.cex = 2)
```

draws the graph

[image]

I was able to select the font size for the node labels, but I can't specify the font size for the arc weights. How can I do?

Comment: For arguments see `?igraph::igraph.plotting`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `edge.label.cex` parameter.

```
g %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "label", value = relations$weight) %>%
  plot(vertex.size=30,vertex.color="white", vertex.label.cex = 2,
     edge.label.cex = 2)
```